# Force HTTPS on entire site?

Tags: .htaccess, https

This question has been asked before but I can't find a solution that works for me.

Basically I have a site, and I want to force on HTTPS, I did through cloudflare's page rules and also tried using .htaccess.

But, now the site doesn't load images/css. I don't want to go through every single file/script just to replace their "example.jpg" to "https://domain.com/example.jpg".

Last time it also wouldn't let me log in.
This is a jcow site, if it matters.

Thanks,
-Gie

Answer (score 0):

Try with .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Nope, same as before.

Comment: That work for all, but not for directory `images` and `css`? No `.htaccess` in these folders ?

Comment: There's only one .htaccess file in the root directory, not in any sub-folders.

Comment: And when you ask images, what is he result (blank, error code) ?

Comment: The page doesn't load them.

Comment: You don't use absolute links with them (with http://) ? Try to add https:// to one...

Comment: I did, and then it could load the css. But jCow is full of .home() calls to get it's links and/or just /folder/file.php

Comment: I don't know what you're reffering to; but if you mean if jcow has a https settings somewhere, no.

Comment: For images, if you don't have `http://` links, it should work. If not, try to change to `https://` or just `//` in the beginning... Sorry no other idea ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create the following CloudFlare Page Rule:

1. If the URL matches - http://*domain.com*
2. CLICK "+ A Setting" and select "Always Use HTTPS"
3. Make sure the ORDER is set to FIRST (optional but recommended)
4. CLICK Save and Deploy

You can find some helpful video tutorials for this and other popular rules at:

https://www.cloudflare.com/features-page-rules/